# how to set a page with center layout using wavemaker

Tags: css, layout, html

I want a page with center layout. I've set layout's properties but still not working.Can anyone please help me? Below are the properties which I've set:

width : 100%
height : 100%
layoutkind : left-to-right
horizontalAlign : center
verticalAlign : top

Can anyone please guide me how to set a page with center layout in wavemaker?

Comment: Sorry to hear that `margin: 0 auto` wasn't available in Wavemaker. Googling the issue doesn't reveal much for me, so best of luck - I've deleted my answer so your question doesn't appear that it may be solved, but leaving this comment for other potential answerers.

Comment: Thanks.Hope I'll get the correct answer soon.Otherwise Its difficult get help on topics related to wavemaker.I've tried to write css code for the same also but still it didnt work.

Comment: I've used its Page Layout component..It appears in the center now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are styling the properties for the container widget to get the widgets inside that container to be centered.

For example, drag a panel into the canvas. Set width=100%, height=100%, horizontal-align=centered. Now drag any widget inside that panel. The widget will be centered.

Hope this helps.